# wwwroot folder in asp.net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, wwwroot

I have just created a new ASP.NET Core web application and selected an empty project template. I am using Visual Studio Community 15.7.1.

Upon a first look at the solution explorer I can see no "wwwroot" folder there. Does anyone happen to know if with asp.net core 2.2 the wwwroot is not visible any longer?

I checked the documentation and I could not find anything. No issues in creating another folder and serve my static files from there but I was just curious.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By design empty project template would not add `wwwroot` folder, `controllers` folders, `models` folder and so on.

Comment: Thanks Tanvir, it does if I select asp.net core 2.0

Comment: It really shouldn't. Only the ASP.NET Core MVC tempaltes should have it

Answer (score 51):

Try adding a new folder to the project and call it `wwwroot`. It should take on the appearance with the proper icon and work as expected. This always happens to me with .NET Core web apps when I use the empty project template. This is occurring in `VS 2017 v15.9.3.`

Answer (score 30):

After manually creating the wwwroot folder, we need to add the staticFile middle-ware in the Configure() method of Startup file, as shown below inorder to serve the static file.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        //Adding static file middleware
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
    }
```

We can also rename the default wwwroot folder as we want for an example, if we want to rename it as content

we need to call UseWebRoot() method to configure Content folder as a web root folder in the Main() method of Program class as shown below.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWebRoot("Content")
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Comment: Upvoted this answer.  But added a caveat in my answer about adding a file to the wwwroot folder.

Comment: What about security is this way safe?

Comment: Why is this different in .NET core 2.1? In 2.1 and below, in an empty project all of this is already done for you (wwwroot folder is automatically created, etc). Why did they remove this from .NET Core Web Applications in version 2.2 and above?

Answer (score 19):

you must add folder manually and then rename it to `wwwwroot`. vs detect it as launch folder

Comment: lunch folders! Yum!

Comment: Can directly add folder with by name wwwroot

Comment: did you mean launch folder

Answer (score 3):

For future readers:

A.  Read this !   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1   (Or read shiram's excellent answer which briefly sums it up!)

B. (More practical).  You need to put some kind of file inside the "wwwroot" folder.  And mark it as "Copy Always" or "Copy If Newer".

Example: (typical "rest" aspnetcore project)

```
bin
Controllers
Controllers\ValuesController.cs
obj
Program.cs
Startup.cs
MyCompany.MyTechnology.MyProject.csproj
MyCompany.MyTechnology.MyProject.csproj.user
wwwroot
wwwwroot\StaticContentExampleOne.txt
```

(Mark "StaticContentExampleOne.txt" as "Copy Always" or "Copy If Newer")

Now you should get the wwwroot folder

example:

```
"bin\debug\netcoreapp3.1\wwwroot"
```

and

```
"bin\debug\netcoreapp3.1\wwwroot\StaticContentExampleOne.txt"
```

I don't there is a difference between 2.x and 3.x in this scenario.