# wwwroot folder is not added to a project after running the `dotnet new web`

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-code, project

wwwroot folder is not added to a project after running the `dotnet new web`. Should I just add it manually?

Here is the project structure that I see:

[image]

I am following the tutorial over [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core/first-aspnet-core-application), but instead of a VS I am using the VS Code and the .NET Core CLI. Does it mean that the template created with the help of the `dotnet new web` and with the help of the VS GUI are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be by design that the empty project template with version2.2 and above does not contain `wwwroot` folder.

You could add a new folder to the project and call it `wwwroot`. It should take on the appearance with the proper icon and work as expected. Also , you could use `dotnet new mvc` or `dotnet new webapp` to create a ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller) template which automatically generate `wwwroot` folder.

Reference :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new?tabs=netcore22

[wwwroot folder in asp.net core 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54970400/wwwroot-folder-in-asp-net-core-2-2/56144537)